# How To Scale And Crop An Image Programmatically Following Special Rules

Tags: android, image, scale, crop, rules

I want to scale and crop an image in a specific way before displaying it - depending of its initial dimensions and its width and height proportion. In the end I want the image to fill the entire usable screen.

Here are the rules that I need to follow for scaling and cropping:

1. if the image's width is bigger than its height:
   a) scale up or down the image's height as to match the screen's height but keeping the image's initial width/height ratio.
   b) center the image in the screen.
   c) crop symetrically the excess width space in both sides to match the screen's width.
2. if the image's width is smaller than its height:
   a)scale up or down the image's width as to match the screen's width but keeping the image's initial width/height ratio.
   b) center the image in the screen.
   c) crop symmetrically the excess height space in both sides to match the screen's height.

My intention is to fill the entire screen with the image by stretching or shrinking the dimension which when matches the screen's dimension causes the other image dimension to exceed the screen's size which should then be centered and cropped symmetrically.

My current code makes any image fill the screen but it does not keep the original width/height ratio which causes a distortion.
Below I present the relevant code:

```
Bitmap bmImg;
String[] PathsArray;
int numb_paths=0;
int position = 0;
ImageView imageView;
ViewFlipper flipper;
PathsArray = imagesPaths.split("\n");
numb_paths = PathsArray.length;
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PathsArray[position]);
imageView = new ImageView(displayImagesShow.this);
flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);
Resources r = getResources();
layers[0] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmImg);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.flowers_frame1);
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
ViewFlipper.LayoutParams lp =
        new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams
                (ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
flipper.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. It is located between the long rows of “/” below:

```
Bitmap bmImg,CroppedBmp;
String[] PathsArray;
int numb_paths=0;
int position = 0;
int wi,hi, wc, half_crop_dif, ;
double ratioB
ImageView imageView;
ViewFlipper flipper;
PathsArray = imagesPaths.split("\n");
numb_paths = PathsArray.length;
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PathsArray[position]);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
wi = bmImg.getWidth();
hi = bmImg.getHeight();
ratioB = (double)wi/hi;
if(ratioB>ratio)
{
    wc = (int)(hi*ratio);
    half_crop_dif = (int)((wi-wc)/2.0);
    hi = (int)(hi*CORRECTION_FACTOR);
    CroppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap
            (bmImg, half_crop_dif,0,wc,hi);
    
}
else
{
    hc = (int) (wi / ratio);
    half_crop_dif = (int) ((hi - hc )/ 2.0);
    CroppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap
    (bmImg, 0, half_crop_dif, wi, hc);
}
bmImg = CroppedBmp;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
imageView = new ImageView(displayImagesShow.this);
flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);
Resources r = getResources();
layers[0] = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmImg);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.flowers_frame1);
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
ViewFlipper.LayoutParams lp =
        new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams
                (ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewFlipper.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
flipper.addView(imageView);
```